# Parsererror for local JSON file using $.getJSON - but parsing responseText works. Why?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse a local JSON file using the code below. Basically, the success function is never called because of a parsererror but when I retry to parse the responseText, everything seems fine:

```
$.getJSON('./data/fixtures/teams.txt?callback=?', function(json) {
    // never called because of parsererror
}.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
    var json = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText)); // this works!
    $.each( json.teams, function( index, team ) {
            console.log(team.title);
    });
}
);
```

This is the content of teams.txt:

```
{"teams":[{"key":"irn","title":"Iran","code":"IRN"}]}
```

I copy-pasted the text into http://jsonviewer.stack.hu and it gave me no error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a JSONP call, you better do it like (at least that's the way I do it):

```
$.ajax({
    url: './data/fixtures/teams.txt',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json) {
        $.each( json.teams, function( index, team ) {
            console.log(team.title);
        });
    }
});
```

And if it is not a **JSONP call**, so **you should remove `callback` from url**.

Comment: *"It seems like a JSONP call because of callback= in your url, whereas you call it just like a json xhr request"* Didn't you know that `$.getJSON` makes a JSONP request if the URL contains `callback=?`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp . The `callback=?` is not invalid, the `?` gets replaced by jQuery with a dynamically generated function name. I'm surprised this answer "solved" the problem since it's exactly the same, besides adding code to the success handler. In any case, your explanation is wrong.

Comment: @FelixKling: thanks for pointing this out, I think the reason why it is accepted is because of the last sentence, I guess OP has removed the callback from url and it has got solved.

Comment: Probably. Would still be nice to know exactly why :)

Comment: Yes, removing "callback?" actually solved the problem. Until 30min ago, I did not know the difference between JSON and JSONP. Ahem.. :-)